# Haskell persistent one to many query

Tags: haskell, monads, yesod, persistent

While using Persistent in Yesod I was thinking about how the monad do notation chains off of the previous value:

```
getListR :: ListId -> Handler Html
getListR listId =  do
  list <- runDB $ get404 listId
  items <- runDB $ selectList [ItemListId ==. listId] [Desc ItemId]
  defaultLayout $ do
    $(widgetFile "list")
```

Rather than accepting a (listId list) of type (Key List) in the filter it accepts listId of type List -> Key List and just chains. Does this mean I can only pass queried values to selectList via the previous query? How does this work if I need to filter based off of multiple past queries?

For example I'm thinking to this effect:

```
getListR :: ListId -> UserId -> Handler Html
getListR listId userId =  do
  list <- runDB $ get404 listId
  user_lists <- runDB $ selectList [UserId ==. userId] [Desc UserListsId]
  items <- runDB $ selectList [ItemListId ==. listId list, UserId ==. userId user_lists] [Desc ItemId]
  defaultLayout $ do
    $(widgetFile "list")
```

Is this even possible? Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand. What would you expect/like to be retured from the last items query? Something like all items belonging to a given list authored by a given user?

Comment: select * from items where item_list_id == <list_id> and user_id = <user_lists id>; 
Does that make any more sense?

All I'm really trying to do is run one query based off of two previous queries in the same do block.